# Edit Spreadsheets at Google Drive with Gdata (Java)

Tags: java, gdata, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to edit a public spreadsheet (key = 0Av4aUydPYoNAdHV2MnRaSFhrY0NSZnNOS28yTlhRTVE) on my google_drive using Java and gdata api, but without success.
I change the url from https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/private/full to https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/0Av4aUydPYoNAdHV2MnRaSFhrY0NSZnNOS28yTlhRTVE/private/full , but returns:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request

What does this mean?

Comment: please add your code and the complete error message

Comment: Ok, code at http://pastebin.com/kJ9r0kLW ...
Error message at http://pastebin.com/FC2vZivS

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using is invalid, the correct one has `/private/` instead of `/public/`, as in:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/0Av4aUydPYoNAdHV2MnRaSFhrY0NSZnNOS28yTlhRTVE/private/full

Comment: If I change _private_ instead of _public_ the code above returns:
> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found

Comment: Weird, I can open that link directly from my browser

Comment: Can you add authorization to your service and try again?

Comment: Yah, with authorization (my user and pass) works perfectly. But I don't want my user and password in the java code. Any ideia to access the public document without credentials?

Comment: You have to publish a document to make it accessible by anyone: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#publishing_documents_by_publishing_a_single_revision